# Ckeditor : stylesSet not working when i set a custom allowedContent

Tags: ckeditor

In my Ckeditor config i have a custom allowedContent. I don't use `allowedContent:true` because i don't want to allow the style attribute in the span tags

So this is my allowedContent

```
allowedContent : 'span[class]; a[!href](*);  caption; div; em; h1; h2; h3; h4; h5; h6; hr; i; img; li;  ol; p[*]{*}; pre; strong; sub; sup; table; thead; tbody; tfoot; td; th; tr; tt; u; ul; dl; dt; dd; iframe;'
```

With this configuration, the style attributes are not allowed anymore on the span tags

The problem is with my stylesSets :

```
stylesSet:
      - { name: "style 1", element: ['div', 'p', 'a', 'span'], attributes: { class:"display_only_in_popup" } }
      - { name: "style 2", element: ['div', 'p', 'a', 'span'], attributes: { class:"blockquote" } }
      - { name: "style 3", element: ['div', 'p', 'a', 'span'], attributes: { class:"note" } }
      - { name: "style 4", element: ['p', 'span'], attributes: { class:"highlight" } }
      - { name: "style 5", element: 'span', attributes: { class:"visuallyhidden" } }
```

Before, when i had `allowedContent:true`, i was able to see and use all of my 5 stylesets, but now, for some reason, i only see the "style 5" in the Styles field

Is it possible to keep my 5 stylesets without using `allowedContent:true`?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I would leave `allowedContent` to its default value and make changes instead to `extraAllowedContent`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your 5 stylesets all use the `class` attribute, but your `allowedContent` rule only allows the `class` attribute for the `span` elements.

I suggest changing the `allowedContent` rule to:

```
allowedContent : '*[class]; a[!href](*);  caption; div; em; h1; h2; h3; h4; h5; h6; hr; i; img; li;  ol; p[*]{*}; pre; strong; sub; sup; table; thead; tbody; tfoot; td; th; tr; tt; u; ul; dl; dt; dd; iframe;'
```

or if you want to be more explicit:

```
allowedContent : 'div[class]; p[class]; a[class]; span[class]; a[!href](*);  caption; div; em; h1; h2; h3; h4; h5; h6; hr; i; img; li;  ol; p[*]{*}; pre; strong; sub; sup; table; thead; tbody; tfoot; td; th; tr; tt; u; ul; dl; dt; dd; iframe;'
```

Please refer to the [documentation here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules-section-2).

Note: I was not able to test this code, please let me know in the comments if it does the job.